# Как отредактировать значение в реестре с помощью winreg?

Tags: python, реестр, winreg

Я хочу менять значение DisallowRun при определенных условиях. Использую библиотеку winreg.
Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь пробраться по указанному пути, то мне почему-то отказывает в доступе. Подскажите пожалуйста как это грамотно сделать?

Вот мой код, тут я пока что делаю примерку, но уже на данном этапе отказывает в доступе:

```
with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path, 0, access=winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as key:
    existing_path_value = winreg.EnumValue(key, 0)
    print(existing_path_value)
```

[image: Скрин из реестра]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: в реестр надо ходить с правами администратора

Comment: @Эникейщик как это реализовать в коде?

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:**

Функции, которая меняет значение в реестре, а именно в политике, надо дать права администратора. Сделать это можно двумя методами:

1. Использовать pyqadmin
2. Использовать elevate